# Spring listener after ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder handler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm trying to reconfigure the `SchedulerFactoryBean` on `EnvironmentChangeEvent`(I'm posting to /refresh endpoint).
The problem is that my listener is called before `ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder` handler and I'm getting not up-to-date  configuration properties. They are defined with refresh scope :

```
@RefreshScope
@ConfigurationProperties("pnr2xdf")
public class MyProperties{
public String triggerExpression;
}
```

My `EnvironmentChangeEvent` handler bean is defined with `@Order(value = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` but this doesn't help as `ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder` has the same order.

I know that I can explicitly force rebinding with `ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder.rebind()` but this will cause rebind being called twice.

What is the recommended way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Don't remember, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
@AutoConfigureAfter(name = "org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration")
public class ConfigChangeListenerAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnClass(name = "org.springframework.cloud.context.environment.EnvironmentChangeEvent")
    public DemoConfigChangeListener demoConfigChangeListener() {
        return new DemoConfigChangeListener();
    }

}
```

Comment: Adding few words would be nice, also, see the age of the question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).